# Volley StringRequest with UTF-8 characters - Android

Tags: android, request, android-volley

I'm sending request to server to update row in db. In URL I'm using Cyrillic characters, something like this:

```
localhost/API/BSSR/UpdateZabeleshka?NalogID=2774&Zabeleska=Nescaffe%20Без%20Мраз%20|%20
```

So when I send this request it update the row in db, but instead of characters it write all ??????

Here is my code:

```
private void updateZabeleska() {
        StringRequest updateZabeleska = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            Json.updateZabeleska(nalogID, zabeleska),
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {
                        updateZabeleskaResponse(response);
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.println("Cannot connect to server... (updateZabeleska)");
                }
            });
    queue.add(updateZabeleska);
}

private void updateZabeleskaResponse(String response) {
    response = Json.beautifyJSON(response);

    if (response.equals("false")) {
        System.out.println("FALSE... (updateZabeleskaResponse)");
    } else {
        System.out.println("TRUE... (updateZabeleskaResponse)");
    }
}
```

Json.updateZabeleska(nalogID, zabeleska) returns the comlete URL

Answer (score 0):

Seems that in your server side the database does not accept those characters.  I recommend you to encode thw cyrillic characters to store in the database and decode it in your Android app.